OBD2 Codes Keep Changing
1997 Pontiac Sunfire 2.4L
I took my car to AutoZone and had them use their scanner. No codes were found. Five minutes down the road the check engine light came on so I stopped at another AutoZone. They found one confirmed code. I wonder why the scan triggered the check engine light?
I borrowed a basic OBD2 scanner from someone and started using it about 8 times over the course of a couple weeks. I started to notice that the confirmed and pending codes were changing each time I used it. For example there would be three confirmed codes and three pending. The next time there would be two confirmed and two pending and only two of the them would be the same as before. I tried the rescan function on the OBD2 scanner a couple times and even this showed that some or all of the codes changed.
The next thing I did was unplug the throttle body position sensor to trigger a code on purpose. It worked and this code stayed present between scans even after I plugged the sensor back in. After the very last scan I did, I cleared the current codes and the check engine light hasn’t come back on. There are still pending codes that show up when I scan now.
Is this normal behavior for codes to change?
I want to confirm my OBD2 system is working right before I look into all the codes that showed up in the different scans. It seems odd for the codes to change so frequently and for none of them to come back even two weeks after clearing them.

Can you add the codes that appeared each time to your question?

Are you aware of every USA vehicle under OBDI and OBDII emissions control, performs self testing on every ignition on, engine startup, driving and shutdown? This might be described as live emissions testing and monitoring. When an error code(s) is/are generated, self tests/monitoring halts at the last test and waits until the problem is corrected to continue while resetting the error code(s) on its own without manually resetting with either battery disconnect or pushing a reset on a reader or scantool. Pending codes may require several engine start/drive cycles before the code goes away.
